# MySQL Show available times?

Tags: php, mysql

```
+-----------+----------+------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| bookingID | schoolID | customerID | instructorID | bookingDate | bookingStartTime | bookingStopTime |
+-----------+----------+------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
|         1 |        1 |          1 |           15 | 2015-01-01  | 09:00:00         | 10:00:00        |
|         2 |        1 |          1 |           15 | 2015-01-01  | 15:00:00         | 16:00:00        |
|         3 |        1 |          1 |           15 | 2015-01-01  | 12:00:00         | 13:30:00        |
|         4 |        1 |          1 |           15 | 2015-01-01  | 11:00:00         | 12:00:00        |
+-----------+----------+------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

The above table shows customer bookings (bookingDate, bookingStartTime, bookingStopTime).

I'm trying to figure out an SQL query that will allow me to query the table and find all available times/slots for a given day for a specific amount of time.

For example, a customer requests a 1 hour booking on the 1st Jan 2015 and we are open from 09:00 to 17:00.  I would like to query the table and receive the following results...

```
10:00 > 11:00
14:00 > 15:00
16:00 > 17:00
```

Is this possible with just SQL or would I need some PHP in there also?

I have also tried a few queries by using datetime fields instead of date (as show above).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to join with a table that lists all the hours.

Comment: You *can* join a table that lists all hours, but you don't *need* to.

Comment: I'd rather not have another table listing hours as I should be able to specify the hours in the SQL?

Comment: Well, as a caveat to what I said above, you *do* need to identify which days you're open (or closed)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  your_table 
WHERE 
  bookingDate = '$your_date' AND 
  ('$your_start_time' >= bookingStartTime AND '$your_start_time' < bookingStopTime OR 
  (bookingStartTime >= '$your_start_time' AND bookingStartTime < '$your_end_time'))
```

The query will give you all the hours which are available during the day. (You may add the time constraint for the opening hours)